# Using an IF statement in MySQL to include all results

Tags: mysql

In my SQL statement I'm querying 2 tables to get labels and links for a navbar. The query checks `site_menu` for the `label` and `page_id` to then get the `filename` from the `site_pages` table.

The problem I'm having is that there can be dropdown menus, so that `label` for a dropdown won't have an associated `page_id`, but I still want it to be returned in the results.

I believe there may be If/ELSE functionality I could add to the SQL statement??

```
     SELECT
      site_menu.page_id,
      site_menu.label,
      site_pages.filename
     FROM
      site_menu,
      site_pages
     WHERE
      site_menu.site_id = 1
     AND
      site_menu.parent_id = 0
     AND
      site_pages.id = site_menu.page_id
     ORDER BY
      site_menu.ord
     ASC
```

Comment: You probably need to use a `LEFT JOIN` rather than your implicit `INNER JOIN`

Comment: Thanks. Post as answer and I'll accept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should replace your implicit `JOIN` (`,`) with a `LEFT JOIN` so that your query returns results regardless of whether an entry exists in the `site_pages` table:

```
 SELECT
  site_menu.page_id,
  site_menu.label,
  site_pages.filename
 FROM
  site_menu
 LEFT JOIN
  site_pages
 ON
  site_pages.id = site_menu.page_id
 WHERE
  site_menu.site_id = 1
 AND
  site_menu.parent_id = 0
 ORDER BY
  site_menu.ord
 ASC
```